# Error installing package PloGO

Tags: r, installation, package, install.packages

When I download the zip file of package PloGo from [this link](http://www.proteome.org.au/ArticleDocuments/92/PloGO_2.0_RV3_0_1.zip.aspx), and try to install it on windows R v3.0.1, using the following command:

```
install.packages("PATH/FILENAME.zip", repos=NULL)
```

It returns the "No such file or directory" error, while the file directory is true.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probablly you have not set the path correct. So the easiest way to do this will be using this piece of command.

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)
```

Comment: @Ali: are you using some IDE like rStudio?

Answer (score 0):

The R is looking for DESCRIPTION file inside the package but the package you downloaded contains another folder inside the first level folder (PloGO_2.0_RV3_0_1\PloGO). Unzip the downloaded file and zip the PloGO folder inside it again as PloGO.zip. Use the newly zipped folder (PloGO.zip) as target to to install.